# SpringBoot Application packaging failure but can run normally in IDE

Tags: java, spring-boot

I think the reason for the error is related to MyWebMvcConfigurerAdapter class, which can be packaging successfully by removing it.

program can be packaging successfully by removing MyWebMvcConfigurerAdapter class

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    /**
     * 
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        ApplicationHome home = new ApplicationHome(getClass());
        File jarFile = home.getSource();
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/static/")
            .addResourceLocations("file:"+jarFile.getParentFile().toString()+"\\static\\");
    }
}





Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.hzh.menu.follow_your_heart.client.config.webconfig.MyWebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addResourceHandlers(MyWebMvcConfigurerAdapter.java:27)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addResourceHandlers(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addResourceHandlers(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:490)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef76c66.CGLIB$resourceHandlerMapping$38(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef76c66$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a1243485.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef76c66.resourceHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 12.824 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.hzh.menu.follow_your_heart.FollowYourHeartApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(com.hzh.menu.follow_your_heart.FollowYourHeartApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.018 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I hope the program can be packaging successfully

Comment: The error refers to line 27 in your class, but I can't see the whole class. I suspect its the home.getSource() expression though, which means the line above that does not do what you expect it to do.

Comment: ApplicationHom class in org.springframework.boot.system ApplicationHome

Comment: I'm sure "jarFile.getParentFile().toString()" caused errors, but it only causes errors when it packages to continue unit testing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "packaging"? Are you using maven and issuing "mvn clean package"?

Comment: Yes,I using maven packaging.I am sorry for my poor english

Comment: And did a normal build (mvn clean install) work without problems?

Comment: If packaging choices skip unit tests, no errors will occur

Comment: Errors can also occur when I using install

Comment: Can you add the ApplicationHome class? It would be helpful to see what it does.

Comment: I found that in the context of unit testing,'home.getSource()' it will return null.

Comment: ApplicationHome class is not written by me. It in SpringBoot class library, in the package 'org.springframework.boot.system'

Comment: Thank you very much. By consulting the API documentation, I know that I should use ApplicationHome. getDir (), not ApplicationHome. getSource (). In the unit test environment, getSource () will return null

Answer (score 0):

By consulting the API documentation, I know that I should use ApplicationHome. getDir (), not ApplicationHome. getSource (). In the unit test environment, getSource () will return null.

```
Method Detail
getSource
public File getSource()
Returns the underlying source used to find the home directory. This is usually the jar file or a directory. Can return null if the source cannot be determined.
Returns:the underlying source or null

getDir
public File getDir()
Returns the application home directory.
Returns:the home directory (never null)
```